# Does the Crystal Report 10 runtime bundled in VS 2008 needs .Net Framework 3.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, .net-3.5, crystal-reports

Do I need to install .NET Framework 3.5 for my deployment if I use VS2008's Crystal Report Viewer - version 10?

My target deployment is just for .NET Framework 2.0 and I have to install with the minimum framework requirements. can I use the previous Report Viewer (VS2005's) in VS2008?

Answer (score 0):

You should run the Crystal Reports MSI after your Application setup.

The MSI can be found in the following locations:

> **Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 (x86)**
>
> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5\CRRedist2008_x86.msi`
>
> **Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 (x64)**
>
> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5\CRRedist2008_x64.msi`
>
> **Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 (IA64)**
>
> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\Crystal
>   Reports\CRRedist\IA64\CRRedist2008_ia64.msi`

Taken from [this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225231.aspx)